# Running computations for each item in a dataframe,then creating a new one with the results: is there anything efficient than a for-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've read that using for-loops to build pandas dataframes is discouraged, but I cannot figure out a more efficient way of doing it for my specific use case.

I have a dataframe `stockdata` that contains stock price data (ticker, date, open, high, low, close, volume). I then slice it to get only stocks that had activity for the latest trading day called `traded`. After that, I run a bunch of computations on each stock in `traded` and append the results to a list of dicts called `data` through a for-loop. I turn the list into a dataframe `today` and from there slice it into smaller dataframes for each condition I'm looking for. The relevant code is below:

```
traded = stockdata.loc[stockdata['date'] == stockdata['date'].max()]
cp = compute() #function I wrote
data = []

for stock in traded['ticker']:
    finder = traded.loc[traded['ticker'] == stock] #traded to get only the current stock
    buzz20 = ((finder['volume'] / cp.sma(stock, 'volume', 20).shift(-1)[:1]) - 1) 
    buzz50 = ((finder['volume'] / cp.sma(stock, 'volume', 50).shift(-1)[:1]) - 1)
    #cp.sma(x, y, z) gets pd.DataFrame.rolling.mean(z) of stockdata where rows are 'x' of values in column 'y'
    #buzzxx compares the current volume to the average of the last xx days
    ti = cp.sma(stock, 'close', 7)[:1] / cp.sma(stock, 'close', 65)[:1]
    #rolling mean of 'close' over 7 days / rolling mean over 65 days
    mid, uboll, lboll = cp.boll(stock, 'close')
    #mid is cp.sma(), uboll and lboll are mid + 2 std dev, and mid - 2 std dev, respectively 
    valtraded = (finder['volume'] * finder['vwap'])
    data.append({'ticker': finder['ticker'].item(),
                 'close': finder['close'].item(),
                 'chg': cp.roc(stock, 'close')[:1].item(),
                 'volume': finder['volume'].item(),
                 'valto': valtraded.item(),
                 '20sma': cp.sma(stock, 'close', 20)[:1].item(),
                 '50sma': cp.sma(stock, 'close', 50)[:1].item(),
                 '100sma': cp.sma(stock, 'close', 100)[:1].item(),
                 '4ema': cp.ema(stock, 'close', 4)[:1].item(),
                 '8ema': cp.ema(stock, 'close', 8)[:1].item(),
                 '21ema': cp.ema(stock, 'close', 21)[:1].item(),
                 'uboll': uboll[:1].item(),
                 '20buzz': buzz20.item(), '50buzz': buzz50.item(),
                 'ti': ti.item(), 'volatility': cp.volatility(stock)[:1].item()
                 })

today = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Unfortunately, running the scanner takes about a minute on average, which I believe is too long since `traded` only has about 200 rows and pandas is normally used for much larger datasets. I'm pretty sure the for-loop is inefficient, but I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: What you want is advice on how to vectorize your solution.  However, what you've presented us requires us to decipher your intent, all of your functions, and figure out how to vectorize it.  Someone else may very well attempt to answer this, I'm just letting you in on the reasons why I'm passing on it.  You'd maximize your chances of getting your questions answered if you presented to us a minimal amount of data and explain the calculation your are attempting then show us what you've tried.  The way it is now feels to much like you asking us to do your work.

Comment: @piRSquared Sorry if my question comes across that way, it wasn't my intention. English is actually my third language so I sometimes have difficulty putting my thoughts into words so my intent might have been lost in translation. If you (or anyone) could tell me what's lacking in the question, I'll gladly edit it. Also re the functions: I'll edit the question with an explanation.

Comment: I understand.  But I'd rather you get some feedback rather than having your question left unanswered and you wondering why.  This way, you might still think how to simplify the question.  Ask how to vectorize one of your calculations.  Explain what the calculation is.  Split it out into several questions.  Believe me, we like questions ;-)